# Settup up mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I was following this quickstart guide, `http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X`, but I got lost when they told me to to execute `./mongodb-xxxxxxx/bin/mongod`, in which directory do I execute this command? I tried to `find / -name mongodb` results matched that directory format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start Mongo, run that command in the root installation directory of mongo, so, assuming you installed mongo in `/opt/mongo/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2`, just run in that folder like this...

```
   /opt/mongo/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2$   ./bin/mongod
```

Add any additional parameters you need to start the instance, this is how I run my instance....

```
./bin/mongod --fork --dbpath /opt/mongo/data/db1/dbs --port 33479 --logpath /opt/mongo/data/db1/log/db1.log -logappend
```

Comment: I don't use mongoose, but if you start mongo on the default port of `27017`, you can try to include the port in the connection string, `'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database'`

Answer (score -1):

My personal favorite way to install just about anything, including MongoDB, on Mac OS X:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
brew install mongodb
```